# QGraphicsItem clipping children.

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

My derived class from QGraphicsItem returns a bounding rect of Rect1.

```
QRectF BaseControl::boundingRect() const {
    return(Rect1);
}
```

Its many children all clip to Rect1.

Instead, How do I get the children to clip to an inner rect Rect2 defined by me while the boundingRect of my QGraphicsItem remains as Rect1?.

Comment: Can you provide more details on the use case you are eventually trying to achieve? Depending on what you need to be able to do within your `Rect1` (receive mouse events, paint content for parent but not children, etc.) there may be a simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you've set the `ItemClipsChildrenToShape` flag on BaseControl. If so, you can simply re-implement `QGraphicsItem::shape()` to define the shape you want the children to clip to, which can be different from `boundingRect()` (`boundingRect()` is the default).

Another option that is probably better is to create a container QGraphicsItem that will be the child of BaseControl, and the parent of the items you want to clip. This container item should have the `ItemClipsChildrenToShape` flag set, but BaseControl should not. That way, BaseControl can have its own bounding rectangle, Rect1, and the container item can have Rect2 as its bounding/clipping rectangle.